# Automatic id rename after title change

Tags: plone, archetypes

What could be the best way to achieve a functionality that

- All items get new id based no title edits automatically, no need to rename items manually
- This would use the id normalization + counter format used by Plone by default
- Can be enabled globally for all Archetypes content types

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yuri's on the right track - for a quick and very dirty, I believe this will work:

```
context.setTitle('lorem ipsum')
context.unmarkCreationFlag()
context.processForm()
```

Strictly, that's not what the documentation says - as it shouldn't do a rename if it doesn't have the temporary ID generated in the portal factory, but I was getting renaming happening when I modified titles of objects that still had the CreationFlag marked

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the fact that this is a bad idea (all your URLs break every time you edit a title), I'd do this with a custom event. You'll have to copy some of the functionality built into Archetypes used when renaming objects on create, because you don't want to rename every time you edit:

```py
from Products.Archetypes.interfaces import (
    IBaseObject,
    IObjectEditedEvent,
)
import re
from zope.component import adapter


endsWithNumber = re.compile('-\d+$')


@adapter(IBaseObject, IObjectEditedEvent)
def renameOnEdit(obj, event):
    old_id = obj.getId()
    without_number = endsWithNumber.sub('', old_id)

    # New id based on Title
    new_id = obj.generateNewId()
    if new_id == old_id or new_id == without_number:
        # No change
        return

    new_id = obj._findUniqueId(new_id)
    if new_id is None:
        # Couldn't find a new unique id (out of sequence numbers?)
        return

    obj.setId(new_id)
```

Comment: This is needed just for initial content import; we will autotranslate LinguaPlone language versions to be used as stub placeholders. The language team will enter their content after which the item gets renamed. In fact, no when you refreshed me regarding the issue, one could simply set _atRenameAfterCreation for batch translated language content.

Comment: Setting `_at_rename_after_creation` will only work if the id is 'autogenerated' and the object is marked as new. You have to call obj._renameAfterCreation() to force the rename yourself (in which case there is no check if the object needs renaming and you'll get 'oldId-1' as the id as it'll find it's own id already taken.

Answer (score 0):

I think archetypes has this built in:

http://plone.org/documentation/kb/richdocument/controlling-creation

If you need more fine-grained control over how titles are generated, you can re-define the _renameAfterCreation() method from 'Archetypes/BaseObject.py'

So redefining it should be the way.

Comment: I think you misundertood: I want rename after every edit, not just after creation